# como actualizo un objeto en indexedDB

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, indexeddb

lo que intento hacer es que si ya he introducido un DNI que ya he guardado lo actualice con el nuevo nombre y nuevo surname
DNI ES MI INDICE UNICO.
mi contenedor indexed esta formado por 4 propiedades id (autoincrement, dni , name , surname .

```js
  var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
        
            var dataBase = null;
                
            function comenzar() {
            
    agregar2=document.getElementById("guardar");
    
    agregar2.addEventListener("click", agregar, false);
    
                dataBase = indexedDB.open("object", 1);
                
                dataBase.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {

                    active = dataBase.result;
                    
                    object = active.createObjectStore("people", { keyPath : 'id', autoIncrement : true });
                    object.createIndex('by_name', 'name', { unique : false });
                    object.createIndex('by_dni', 'dni', { unique : true });
                };

                dataBase.onsuccess = function (e) {
                    alert('Base de datos cargada correctamente');
            loadAll();
                };
        
                dataBase.onerror = function (e)  {
                    alert('Error cargando la base de datos');
                };
    
    agregar=document.getElementById("guardar");
    
    agregar.addEventListener("click", agregar, false);
    
    modificar=document.getElementById("Modificar");
    
    modificar.addEventListener("click", modificar, false);
    
            }
            
            function agregar() {
                var active = dataBase.result;
                var data = active.transaction(["people"], "readwrite");
                var object = data.objectStore("people");
     
     
     
                var request = object.put({
                    dni: document.querySelector("#dni").value,
                    name: document.querySelector("#name").value,
                    surname: document.querySelector("#surname").value
                });

                request.onerror = function (e) {
                    alert(request.error.name + '\n\n' + request.error.message);
                };

                data.oncomplete = function (e) {
                    document.querySelector("#dni").value = '';
                    document.querySelector("#name").value = '';
                    document.querySelector("#surname").value = '';
                    alert('Objeto agregado correctamente');
     
     loadAll();
     
                };
                
            }
window.addEventListener("load", comenzar, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>IndexedDB: Almacenamiento local con HTML5</title>
        <script src="indexed5.js">  </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="dni" placeholder="Introducir dni" />
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Introducir nombre" /> 
        <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Introducir apellidos" />
        <input type="button" id="guardar" value="guardar">
       
        
        
        <hr>
<div id="elements">
    <table>
        <caption>Persons</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>DNI</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th> </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="elementsList">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">Not elements to show</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

comparto mi auto respuesta. logre cumplir el objetivo pero de forma desprolija 
seguire investigando a ver si existe simplificacion del codigo posible

```js
function agregar() {
                var active = dataBase.result;
                var data = active.transaction(["people"], "readwrite");
                var object = data.objectStore("people");
     
     
     
                var request = object.put({
                    dni: document.querySelector("#dni").value,
                    name: document.querySelector("#name").value,
                    surname: document.querySelector("#surname").value
                });

                request.onerror = function (e) {
                   
       
      var active= dataBase.result;
      var data= active.transaction(["people"], "readwrite");
      var object= data.objectStore("people");
       
       var dni2=document.querySelector("#dni").value;
       var index= object.index("by_dni");
       var request = index.get(String(dni2));
       
       
       
       request.onsuccess = function(){
     
      /*var result = request.result;
      console.log(result);
      result.name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
      result.surname = document.querySelector("#surname").value;*/
      
      object.openCursor().onsuccess = function (e){
      
       var result= e.target.result;
       
       if(result===null){return }
       
       console.log(result.value +" "+ dni2);
       if ( result.value.dni == dni2){
       console.log("result= "+ result.value.dni + " dni2= "+ dni2);  
       console.log("actualizando");
       result.value.name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
       result.value.surname = document.querySelector("#surname").value;
       
       var objeto = result.value;
       result.update(objeto);
       console.log("objeto actualizado");
       //loadAll(); //funcion que muestra mis datos en una tabla 
       }//cierre if
       result.continue();
      } //cierre open cursor
     
     data.oncomplete = function (e) {
                    document.querySelector("#dni").value = '';
                    document.querySelector("#name").value = '';
                    document.querySelector("#surname").value = '';
                    //alert('Objeto agregado correctamente');
     
     loadAll();
     
                };
      //console.log(objeto);
       
      
        
       } // cierre requeston success.
       
                }//cierre request on error
    //alert("hola");
                data.oncomplete = function (e) {
                    document.querySelector("#dni").value = '';
                    document.querySelector("#name").value = '';
                    document.querySelector("#surname").value = '';
                    alert('Objeto agregado correctamente');
     
     loadAll();
     
                };
                
            }
```